# Are Trello actions limited?

Tags: trello

There are some cards which do not have a "create" action. I call a "create" action an action which led to the creation of the card which might be creation, copying of the card, etc.
Does anyone have an idea why some cards do not have such actions. Does trello limit the history in some way?